# Prime inequality $P_{n.m}$ $<$ $P^{m}_n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $P_n$ be nth prime, where $n,m \in$ $\mathbb{N}$, $n,m >1$. 
How i can show that $P_{n.m}$ $<$ $P^{m}_n$.

I tried to used $PNT$ but that feels like overkill, is this inequality already proven?

Comment: What does $P_{n.m}$ mean?

Comment: Here are some examples, $n,m =2$, $P_{4} < P^{2}_2$ $\Longrightarrow$ 
$7<9$.

Comment: It follows from elementary arguments combined with examining cases for small m and an upper bound of Chebyshev, namely the nth prime is less than An log n.  This question is better at math.stackexchange.  Gerhard "Exponential Grows Really, Really, Fast" Paseman, 2018.02.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I conjecture that it follows from Euclid's argument.

Answer (score 7):

First we observe the bound $P_{2n}<3P_n$. We verify this numerically for $n\leq 20$, while for $n\geq 21$ we derive it from (3.11)-(3.12) in Rosser-Schoenfeld: [Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807), Illinois J. Math. 6 (1962), 64-94. Now for $m,n\geq 2$ we get, by repeated applications of the above inequality,
$$P_{nm}\leq P_{n2^{m-1}}<3^{m-1}P_n\leq P_n^m.$$
Done.